# Product Unavailable when inventory type is changed to check quantity on admin panel

Tags: admin, product, broadleaf-commerce

In Broadleaf if i try to add a product using admin pannel with Inventory Type as check quantity,On site its show product unavailable.
It will be great if someone could tell me why is this so or where in admin pannel can i add product quantity.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using broadleaf 3.1.8-GA admin, you could login to admin to admin application and go to section 'Catalog' -> 'Products' -> Select desired product -> Go to 'Inventory' Tab -> Fill in 'Quantity Available'. That's all.

If you need more details, I can add it to my answer.

Comment: Im able to see the Quantity available Field in my local but when i deploy it to server Quantity Available field is not visible :(

Comment: probably you have forgotten to add ``-javaagent:${spring.instrument.path}`` where ${spring.instrument.path} may be a path on your system folder where libraries are located.

``spring.instrument.path=../lib/spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar``

Comment: how to add -javaagent: for a web application?